# Сделать один pipe и применить для разных событий

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Хочу сделать сделать один `pipe` и применять его для разных событий.
Как это правильно сделать?

```js
import { fromEvent } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/_esm2015';
import { map } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/_esm2015/operators';

const search = document.querySelector('input#search');
const myCustomPipe = () => (obs) => obs
  .pipe(
    map(e => e.target.value),
  );

const stream$ = fromEvent(search, 'input');

stream$.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value);
});

stream$.pipe(myCustomPipe());
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подписываться `.subscribe` надо на `Observable`, к которому сделан `.pipe`

```js
const myCustomPipe = () => (obs) => obs.pipe(
  map(e => e.target.value)
);

const stream$ = fromEvent(search, 'input');

stream$.pipe(myCustomPipe()).subscribe(v => {
  console.log(v);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
```